# Failed to instantiate spec 'KernelTest'

Tags: testing, groovy, gradle

I only try spock test, and get "Failed to instantiate spec 'KernelTest'", [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/#folders/0B08GAyjqgToLUGNjbG52ZS1GZDQ/0B08GAyjqgToLfnhpXzlFRGxiemUzVmY4cW02NmRrZmRJdmdtTGZZNUlXdThMREVDMG5HeG8) is my full code

following is my code:

```
// build.gradle
apply plugin: 'groovy'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.3.9'
    compile gradleApi()
    testCompile 'junit:junit:+'
    testCompile project(":ro")
    testCompile 'org.spockframework:spock-core:1.0-groovy-2.3'
}
```

my test is:

```
// KernelTest.groovy

package ro.gd

class KernelTest extends spock.lang.Specification {
    def 'test smth'() {
        expect: 1 == 1

    }
}
```

it raise:

```
ro.gd.KernelTest > initializationError FAILED
    org.spockframework.util.InternalSpockError
        Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError at KernelTest.groovy:-1
            Caused by: groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException at KernelTest.groovy:-1
```

Comment: There are probably version conflicts between spock, gradle and groovy.

Comment: is your kernel test example complete code?  only `expect:` in a body would be an syntactic error.

Comment: @cfrick sorry, i omit "1 == 1"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can get it to work with the latest gradle if I change `ro/build.gradle` to use a specific version of groovy:

```
compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.3.9'
```

And then change the dependencies of `ro-gd/build.gradle` to:

```
dependencies {
    compile gradleApi()
    testCompile project(":ro")
    testCompile 'org.spockframework:spock-core:1.0-groovy-2.3', {
        exclude module: 'groovy-all'
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, since it's my personal repo, i find the better way is instead "compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.3.9'" with "compile localGroovy()"